# Not able to connect to HelloWord Servlet using openshift

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets, openshift

I am newbie to Servlet programming and [Openshift.](https://www.openshift.com/)I am using eclipse [Luna](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/luna) for my sevlet programming.I created New **Dynamic web project** in eclipse with name **Test** and created Simple Servlet to print Hello Word inside java **Resources->src->mypackagename->HelloWord.java**. I am able to run this code and showing "Hello Word" on local Tomcat using URL  http://localhost:9999/Test/HelloWord where **Test** is my project name.

Now i uploaded by project to Openshift Hosting Server using eclipse jboss and Openshift plugins.All step while uploading it to openshift as successful.Also project is showing on my openshift web console.

Issue is i am not able to open my Servlet by calling the link http://test-mydomain.rhcloud.com/Test/HelloWord.I am getting 404 source not found error.What is the proper way to hit my Servlet.Is there any other setting that i need to do on Openshift Console.

Comment: Have you tried using this url ?
http://test-mydomain.rhcloud.com/HelloWord

Comment: Yes i am getting HTTP status 404